# How to set cursor position in TextInput in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to figure out how to keep the focus on my `TextInput` widget, after calling the `on_validate()` method. Such that, after hitting RETURN I can keep typing without having to select the widget with my mouse.

When I read the `TextInput` doc all the cursor options seem to be assuming that the cursor is already in the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs is shows that to set focus on the `TextInput` you do:

```
textinput = TextInput(focus=True)
```

Perhaps you could set focus to True again, at the end of the `on_validate` method.
How you do that exactly will depend on whether you're calling it from the kv file or the `main.py`

For instance, in the kv file it would look something like this:

```
on_validate: mytextinput.focus = True
```

Whereas in the `main.py`, it would require something like this:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(kwargs)

    def on_validate(self):
        #do other stuff perhaps
        self.focus = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below shows how to use Kivy Clock.schedule_once to reset the focus on the TextInput widget after the user pressed Enter to submit the text he entered in the one line Textinput.

```
    commandTextInput = ObjectProperty()
```

...

```
def refocusOnCommandTextInput(self):
    #defining a delay of 0.1 sec ensure the
    #refocus works in all situations. Leaving
    #it empty (== next frame) does not work
    #when pressing a button !
    Clock.schedule_once(self._refocusTextInput, 0.1)       


def _refocusTextInput(self, *args):
    self.commandTextInput.focus = True


#example of calling refocus function after
#having handled new command entry
def submitCommand(self):

    # Get the student name from the TextInputs
    commandStr = self.commandTextInput.text
    #... some processing
    self.refocusOnCommandTextInput()
```

From the .kv file

```
    TextInput:
        id: command
        background_color: 0,0,0,0
        foreground_color: 1,1,1,1
        focus: True
        #ENTER triggers root.submitCommand()
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.submitCommand()
```